# Must helical edge states be protected by time-reversal symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, topological-insulators, topological-phase

In a lattice system that exhibits quantum spin Hall effect (QSHE), like topological insulators in 2D or 3D, we call a pair of counter-propagating gapless edge states with opposite spin **helical edge states**, and we say that they are protected by time-reversal (TR) symmetry.

I was wondering if helical edge states can be protected by symmetries other than TR symmetry, i.e. if they can appear in a system where TR symmetry is broken, but some other symmetries like magnetic space group symmetries (production of space group symmetry and TR symmetry) or parity-time (PT) symmetry are respected?

Theoretical explanation and concrete examples are both helpful! Thanks in advance!